# Calendar displaying multiple calendars in the same view, at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am looking for a way to display multiple calendars. My idea is illustrated in this loose mockup.

[image]

I have looked at the different plugins like FullCalendar, but they are only able to display one calendar at a time.

So I was hoping you guys knew some smart plugins?

**Edit note 1:** I don't want the calendars to be separated, they need to be displayed in the same scrollarea, so to speak.

Comment: See if this can help you (with some more styling): http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cutindex1a.shtml

Answer (score 0):

There is something i stumbled on once.

https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki

and particularlly this demo: http://themouette.github.io/jquery-week-calendar/weekcalendar_demo_3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use FullCalendar to display events from multiple event sources which I think is much more cleaner way as opposed to have three calendars. But if your scenario demands to have multiple calendars, it is also possible with FullCalendar. Here is a quick sample that I did for testing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fullcalendar</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<style>
.cal{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cal1" class="cal">
</div>
<div id="cal3" class="cal">
</div>
<div id="cal2" class="cal">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".cal").fullCalendar({});
})
</script>
```

Comment: That I did not know. However, I don't want the calendars to be separated, they need to be displayed in the same scrollarea, so to speak.